Which endorsing body should I pick for a global talent endorsement? (UK, computer science lecturer/assistant prof)
I'm a UK academic wanting to switch from a skilled worker visa to a global talent visa.
I completed the first step, which was to get a Statement of Guarantee from my university.
Next, I need to apply for an endorsement from an approved endorsing body.
Two of these support CS academics: The Royal Society and The Royal Academy of Engineering, and I need to pick one.

How should I choose the endorser? Are there any pros/cons to either in terms of response time or chance of obtaining the endorsement?


This will depend upon your exact sub-field of CS academics. According to the UK global talent endorsing bodies page:
Royal Academy of Engineering

Algorithms
Artificial intelligence
Computer vision
Data science
H-CI/C-HI
Image processing
Imaging
Informatics
Signal processing
Software engineering
Telecommunications
Web and data science

The Royal Society

Artificial Intelligence
Databases
Human-computing interaction
Machine Learning
New computational paradigms (quantum, biological)
Numerical Computing
Programming Languages and Verification
Security and privacy
Systems, including networking
Vision

As you can see, there is a bit of overlap here. But my understanding is that if most of your research leans heavily into applied CS, the Royal Academy of Engineering would likely be a better fit.
Another metric you can use is to look at who else is publishing in the same journals as you, and see which of the two affiliations is the most common.

There's more than a bit of overlap, I do AI :).
My point is that I think both could potentially endorse, and I wonder how I should pick which one to ask.

AI is the hardest one for sure, but what specifically do you do within AI? Are you working on gradient boosted trees, natural language processing, general neural networks, llms, etc...
Narrowing it down will help.
